# Import local module in a databricks notebook

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I have created two new python notebooks for databricks in /workspace/Shared/Notebooks.

I would share some functions between the both notebooks. I have created a python file containing a few generic functions.

It exists a way to import my functions into my both notebooks ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different methods to achieve this:

- Use the `%run <another_notebook>` to include content of another notebook into a current one ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#run))
- If you use Databricks Repos, it has support for so-called "Files in Repos" - in this case you can use Python or R **files** (*not notebooks!*) as [Python or R modules](https://docs.databricks.com/repos/work-with-notebooks-other-files.html#work-with-python-and-r-modules), so for Python you can just do `import some_file`.

Unit tests in this [demo repository](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo) shows both approaches.

Update 2023rd: there is now also support for Python modules for normal workspace locations

Comment: how to import .py file which is in different directory from the current directory ? %run "<notebook_path> works for any notebook, but how to import .py file ? Thanks !!
Example: test.py inside folder-a, now want to import test file from folder-b. how to do this?

Comment: if `folder-b` is setup correctly (with `__init__.py`), then you can just do `from folder_b.file import *`

Comment: I tried to import a python module under my workspace folder, but the import does not work. Do I need specific databricks runtime to get this feature?

Comment: Yes, 11.3 or higher: https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/workspace.html

Answer (score -1):

It is really easy, when it comes to sharing python code between `.ipynb` files.

Say, you have following files:

```
source.py
dest_1.ipynb
dest_2.ipynb
```

With following contents:

- `source.py`

```py
a = "hello from source"
```

- `dest_1.ipynb` and `dest_2.ipynb`

```py
import source

print(source.a)
```

And you can simply run cells in your notebooks.

The main part is that your source file should be located in the same folder with notebooks.

Comment: does it really work in the Databricks workspace?

Comment: i bet that should be possible to open terminal and create/open files, like in regular server, i would try get information about where the files are stored and how to access them from your environment.

Comment: question was about usage from the notebooks...

Comment: .ipynb file is always jupiter notebook, as Alex has mentioned, "Files in Repos" option should fit your need, because you will have those file stored in same direcotry.